# Install4j - Application no longer listed in "Uninstall a Program" on Windows

Tags: install4j

I'm not sure why, but I think it's since we added the screen "Installation Type" where the application is no longer being listed in Windows "Uninstall a Program". I've looked everywhere I can think of and I can't seem to find anything on how to fix or debug this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry under "Uninstall a program" is created by the "Register Add/Remove item" action which is typically added below the "Installation" screen. You can check the ".install4j/installation.log" file after the installation whether it contains any output for that action (search for the string "RegisterAddRemoveAction").

Comment: Thanks Ingo. And if there are multiple "Installation types" how do you add one per installation type (client, server, etc.) if you can only add one to the list of actions? Or is it one for all? Do you name it with a Installer Runtime Variable that you create?

Comment: Using an installer variable is a good idea. Use a "Set a variable" action for variable "uninstallName" to define a name based on the contents of `context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId")`. Then you can use `${installer:uninstallName}` in the "Item name" property of the "Register Add/Remove item" action.